# GCP Dataflow - getting data from PubSub to report to the sentry

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, sentry

I am wondering if it is possible to get data from pubsub and send it to sentry. I mean:

```
sentry.init(...., integrations=[BeamIntegrations()])
try:
  with Pipeline(optins=options) as pipeline:
  (
    pipeline
    | io.ReadFromPubSub(...) // example message {'f': 'b'}, with attribut id: id1
    | some transaformations...
expect:
  // and any of above throw an error:
  with sentry.push_scope() as scope:
    sentry.set_tag('id': id1 from pubsub message) // ?
    sentry.capture_expection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch errors in `Beam` in this way.

You have to use a dead letter queue with `Beam` and `TupleTags`.

You will have 2 sinks with this system :

- The good sink
- The bad sink

I didn't used `sentry` but I think it's possible to sink the a PCollection to `sentry`.

Example of catching errors with a library called `Asgarde` :

https://github.com/tosun-si/pasgarde

```
pip install asgarde==0.16.0
```

```py
 with Pipeline(optins=options) as pipeline:
  (
    input_collection = pipeline
    | io.ReadFromPubSub(...) // example message {'f': 'b'}, with attribut id: id1

    resut = (CollectionComposer.of(input_collection)
       .map(lambda el : .....)
       .map(lambda el2 : .....)
    )

    result_outputs: PCollection[YourObjectOrDict] = result.outputs

    # Failure object contains error and input element and it's given by Asgarde library
    result_failures: PCollection[Failure] = result.failures

    result_failure | 'Send errors to Sentry' >> beam.Map(your_method_to_send_to_sentry)
```

If it's not possible to send errors to `sentry` in `Beam` pipeline, you can think to another solution :

- The errors can be written to `Bigquery` for analytics
- The errors can be loggued to `Cloud Logging` and then this can fire an email or Slack alerting

You can also catch error and use dead letter queue in native `Beam` code, I propose you an example from my `Github` repository :

https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-python-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/team_league/domain_ptransform/team_stats_transform.py